# Telegram API with PHP not bot

Tags: php, api, twitter, telegram

app using Ionic and have a PHP api backend for this app.

We need to integrate Telegram API messaging in this app, I need to use the API and not bot as we need to retrieve the users contacts to allow them to send new private message.

I have spent over 7 hours on looking for examples and Telegrams docs however still cant find a way to implement this, I wanted to know if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: I think we have a little misunderstanding here. The point of Telegram API is to make your own unofficial Telegram clients app! so you don't necessary need your own server-side backend, and if you do, there is no direct talking between your server and Telegram server. There are only talking between client and Telegram API or client and your backend!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PHP implementation of the telegram mtproto protocol.This project can run on PHP 7, PHP 5.6 and HHVM, only 64 bit systems are supported ATM.

https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto

or

https://daniil.it/MadelineProto